# Asynchronously Load Images in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous

I have a ruby script that's going to get a whole bunch of images from another server, then stitching them all together with ImageMagik, everything is working fine, only problem is that performance isn't good when the number of images I have to fetch increases as they're being loaded synchronously.

I need something that can go and load all of the images asynchronously then tell me when they're all ready so that I can stitch them together.

I'm not looking for a background process as there's a user waiting around at the other end of this request expecting a stitched together image.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: What would it mean to do this asynchronously in the foreground?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a library like [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) to fetch the images. It can perform HTTP requests in parallel.